# Node app doesn't recognize function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

So, I'm writing a Node app, and I'm trying to add a function to be called when a new user is created. I'm using the Twilio API in order to send a SMS message to someone once a user signs up for the app.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var db = require('./models');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
var twilio = require('./js/twilio.js');

// app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.post("/signup", function (req, res) {
  // Creating object to pass into db and twilio:
  var new_user = {
    first_name : req.body.first_name,
    last_name : req.body.last_name,
    phone : req.body.phone,
    partner_phone : req.body.partner_phone,
    email : req.body.email,
    password : req.body.password
  };
console.log("The new_user is: ", new_user)
  twilio.send_sms_to(new_user);
  db.User.create({first_name: new_user.first_name, last_name: new_user.last_name,     phone: new_user.phone, partner_phone: new_user.partner_phone, email:     new_user.email, password: new_user.password}).then(function(user){
        res.render("login");
    });
});
```

twilio.js

```
var send_sms_to = function (user) { 
var client = new twilio.RestClient('secret key', 'super secret key'),  msg =     "Hello potential new user!",
  phone = user.partner_phone,
  name = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name;
  console.log("Entries are: ", user.phone, user.first_name)
  client.sms.messages.create({
    to: phone,
    from:'+16507970229',
    body: msg
}, function(error, message) {
    // The HTTP request to Twilio will run asynchronously. This callback
    // function will be called when a response is received from Twilio
    // The "error" variable will contain error information, if any.
    // If the request was successful, this value will be "falsy"
    if (!error) {
        // The second argument to the callback will contain the information
        // sent back by Twilio for the request. In this case, it is the
        // information about the text messsage you just sent:
        console.log('Success! The SID for this SMS message is:');
        console.log(message.sid);
        console.log('Message sent on:');
        console.log(message.dateCreated);
    } else {
        console.log('Oops! There was an error.');
    }
  });
}`
```

But every time I run the post request I get an error

TypeError: twilio.send_sms_to is not a function

at /Users/jamesbradley/codeProjects/indulge/indulge_app/app.js:256:10

(this is the line "twilio.send_sms_to(new_user);" in the app.js file)

...even though Nodemon runs the server with no issues. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just seems like a simple path issue on your server.  Apparently, `require('./public/js/twilio.js');` isn't the right path to your `twilio.js`.

Comment: The path to `twilio.js` in `app.js` and the error output don't match, with the error lacking the leading period (`.`). Are there any other places where `twilio.js` is being required that may be leading to the error?

Comment: I've tried everything and can't figure out how to fix the path:
('./public/js/twilio.js')
('./js/twilio.js')
('../public/js/twilio.js')
('../js/twilio.js')
('public/js/twilio.js')
('js/twilio.js')

Comment: Can you `console.log(twilio)` at the beginning of your `app.js` and give us the result?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you just forgot to export the `send_sms_to` function in your `twilio.js` file.

Try adding `module.exports.send_sms_to = send_sms_to;` at its end. Otherwise he won't be part of the module when you import it somewhere else.

If I am right, you may want to learn more about node.js modules [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html).